# Branch.io sessions vs deep link routing

Tags: android, branch.io

Using Branch.io their documentation says that you should start the session in onStart like so

```
Branch branch = Branch.getInstance();

branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener(){
    @Override
    public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {
        if (error == null) {
            // params are the deep linked params associated with the link that the user clicked -> was re-directed to this app
            // params will be empty if no data found
            // ... insert custom logic here ... // <--- NOTE THIS PLEASE
        } else {
            Log.i("MyApp", error.getMessage());
        }
    }
}, this.getIntent().getData(), this);
```

Although my app is always opened with the branch link the inInitFinished method is never called.

So I dug a bit further in the doc and found out about the deep link routing which says to handle everything in onResume like so:

```
super.onResume();
if (Branch.isAutoDeepLinkLaunch(this)) {
    try {
        String autoDeeplinkedValue = Branch.getInstance().getLatestReferringParams().getString("product_picture");
        launch_mode_txt.setText("Launched by Branch on auto deep linking!"
                + "\n\n" + autoDeeplinkedValue);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} else {
    launch_mode_txt.setText("Launched by normal application flow");
}
```

Although my app is opened with the link the try/catch is never reached again.

Which one should I use to handle the activity when opened with deep links?

Answer (score 0):

Alex from Branch.io here: these two methods actually work together and serve difference purposes.

### `onStart()`

This initializes your Branch session, and is executed whenever the initial splash `Activity` ([as defined by the intent filter in your Manifest file](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/android/#register-a-uri-scheme)) loads. You *can* do everything related to routing right here, and this is also the place where you would begin building a [custom link routing method](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/deep-link-routing/advanced/android/#building-a-custom-deep-link-routing-method) if you want something advanced.

### `onResume()`

The snippet you're referring to is from our [automatic deep link routing method](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/deep-link-routing/guide/android/). The reason this is separate is because you're actually doing this in a *different* `Activity` from where you have the `onStart()` call. The flow is that your app first goes through the `Activity` with the `onStart()` call, and then is routed to the `Activity` with the `onResume()` call to display the deep link content.

The `isAutoDeepLinkLaunch()` call in that snippet is needed only if you are using the automatic deep link routing method (enabled in the Manifest file). You use this method to determine if the activity is launched by a the `AutoDeeplinking` feature. Note that auto-deeplinking is different from opening your app on a link click, and is used for automatically navigating to a particular activity after opening a link if you don't decide to build a more complex deep link routing method of your own.

My hunch for why you're not getting through `onInitFinished()` is that you may still need to [enable auto session management](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/android/#enable-auto-session-management). Check that and let me know if you're still having trouble!